# Why is time coming as 0000 when i am using the todays date in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, string-formatting

I am trying to create a string to show the current date and time without wanting to use any slashes just the numbers.

For example, `09 jun 2011 11AM` should be `201109061100`

But when i run the below code the time is always `0000`

Output:

```
ResultLog201109060000
```

Code:

```
DateTime currDate = DateTime.Today;
String resultlogFilename;
resultlogFilename = 
    "ResultLog" + 
    currDate.ToString("yyyy") + 
    currDate.ToString("dd") + 
    currDate.ToString("MM") + 
    currDate.ToString("HH") + 
    currDate.ToString("mm");
```

Any idea how to get the correct time?

Comment: In addition to answers below, also note that you can combine your `ToString` calls into one call `ToString("yyyyddMMHHmm")`, see @Alex's answer.

Comment: the 0000 or +0000 i think it's the timezone  anyhow you can format the date and get rid of it pretty easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DateTime.Today seems to return the Date part not the hour part.

Just use **DateTime.Now** to get a complete time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx

**Msdn DateTime.Today**

Because it returns the current date without the current time, the Today property is suitable for use in applications that work with dates only. For details, see Choosing Between DateTime, DateTimeOffset, and TimeZoneInfo. In contrast, the TimeOfDay property returns the current time without the current date, and the Now property returns both the current date and the current time.

Answer (score 3):

```
var resultlogFilename = string.Format("ResultLog{0:yyyyddMMhhmm}", DateTime.Now);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) instead of .Today. "Today" filters out the "time" part, so it effectively returns midnight (0:00).

Answer (score 0):

It is because today returns to you only todays date and not todays time :)